# Navigation menu with edit action sub menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

In a web application I have a vertical menu built using a `<ul>`. There's nothing particularly fancy about it. Each `<li>` just has some padding and color.

I'm trying figure out how to create an action menu so that when you mouse over one of the `<li>`'s a little menu shows up right below it snapped to the right of the `<ul>` margin partially visible, then fully visible when you mouse over the actions themselves. Kind of like how it works in Word 2007+ when you have a chunk of text highlighted:

[image]

In this case the actions would be things like edit, delete, move up, move down.

Here's my basic layout:

```
<div id="nav-menu">
    <div class="tab-control-menu">some action items</div>
    <ul id="tab-list">
        <li class="nav-item tab">
            <a tab="tab1" tab-id="1" class="selected tab">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item tab">
            <a tab="tab2" tab-id="2" class="tab">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item tab">
            <a tab="tab3" tab-id="3" class="tab">Tab 3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item tab">
            <a tab="tab4" tab-id="4" class="tab">Tab 4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="new-tab">Add New...</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What's the best way to build such an action menu?

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: I've updated to include the HTML. I don't have any JavaScript yet.

Comment: Please try something even if you think it's not going to work. Then we can guide you further with your code.

Comment: I'm not asking for anyone to write the thing for me, I'm asking where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jquery then this will work for you

**JS**

```
    $(function () {
        var controls = $('#controls');

        controls.hover(function(){
           $('a', $(this)).css('opacity', 1);
        },function(){
           $('a', $(this)).css('opacity', 0.3);
        });

        function hideControls(){
           controls.fadeOut('fast');
        }

        $('.close', controls).click(function(){
           hideControls();
        })

        $('.nav-item').hover(function(){
           var off = $(this).offset()
           controls.css({
              opacity: 1,
              display: 'block',
              left: off.left + 20,
              top: off.top + 20
           });
        }, function(){

        })
     })
```

**CSS**

```
     #controls{display: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background: #fff; border: 1px solid #eee; padding: 20px 5px;}
     #controls a{opacity: 0.3}
     #controls a:hover{background:#eee}
     #controls .close{font-size: small; background: #000; padding: 3px; color:#fff}
     #nav-menu .tab{width: 100px; background:#ffc}
```

***addition* to the markup**

```
  <span id="controls">
     <a href="#" id="c1">control 1</a>
     <a href="#" id="c2">control 2</a>
     <a href="#" id="c3">control 3</a>
     <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
  </span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gybUj/.

Same can be achieved with pure CSS too I think.

Comment: This is a pretty good starting point for what I was looking to do. I didn't mean for you to build it up for me though. :) I do appreciate it though. I was more looking for pointers or resources for thinking about how this should be built. Maybe my question could have been better worded. This does help tremendously.

Comment: Glad it helped you. You can start by analyzing and understand this code. You'll learn many jQuery concepts along the way :)

Answer (score 1):

I would add popup elements after each item if the list is short, like:

```
<li class="box">Box</li>
```

Hide it from the beginning, using `display: none`, then show it when the list item is hovered over:

```
li.nav-item:hover + .box, .box:hover {
    display: block;
}
.box {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.box:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

You're going to have to tweak the behaviour, perhaps use JS to append the elements if the list is long.

http://jsfiddle.net/4unLH/

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know about the + in css. How would that work if I didn't want that box to affect the layout of the rest of the ul, e.g. floating above the element below?

Comment: Add `position: absolute` for the box. You'd probably have to style the positions further, but it would float on top of the other items.