# how to get the details of a tab when mouse is kept on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to design a website. i have some tabs in the home page i wanted to do as shown in the screenshot. In the screenshot when i am placing the pointer in the javaL it is displaying the contents.Please suggest me how to do that

[image]

Comment: Looks like `onmouseover` event in the component.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865934/navigation-menu-with-edit-action-sub-menu/15866177#15866177. It's quite similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you specify your code? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
HTML CODE

```
<li class="box">Box</li>
```

CSS

```
li.nav-item:hover + .box, .box:hover {
    display: block;
}
.box {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
.box:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Take A look at this
http://jsfiddle.net/4unLH/

Comment: when we are using any jquery then it shows the status that we are using jquery.com. This means that we can not use it in offline mode(when no internet connection). Can it be done in offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with div and javascript with z-index property of css.